# Laravel eloquent Int greater then column but lest then other column

Tags: laravel-5

I have a weird problem and can't understand why it happens.

I have a table where row has `start` = 300 and `end` = 400.

When I try to filter:

```
     $price = 320;

     Price::where('start', '>=', $price)->where('end', '<=', $price)->first()
```

And I have always an empty result. All columns set to an integer. '$price' is an integer. Why I get an empty result, have no idea...

Comment: I think your column `start` and `end` store with `varchar` datatype?

Comment: The comparisons are reversed: `Price::where('start', '<=', $price)->where('end', '>=', $price)->first()`

Comment: @GautamPatadiya all INT mate.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it is working but i dont get it. Why? )))) Sorry if im so stupid. Can you explain why? 320 is greater then 300,  so `start` has to return false?

Comment: You have to read it like this: 300 (`start`) <= 320 (`$price`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails because you're saying get price where the `start` is greater than or equal to 320 (yours is 300 so fails here) AND where `end` is less than or equal to 320 (yours is 400 so technically this passes)

but since you are doing an AND query the whole query returns nothing.

Try this

```
Price::where('start', '>=', $price)->orWhere('end', '<=', $price)->first();
```

or this

```
Price::where('start', '<=', $price)->where('end', '>=', $price)->first();
```